# Any higher level maths or theories for epicycloids and/or hypocycloids?

Tags: circles, algebraic-curves

For my 12 grade folio task on cycloids, I need to research hypocycloids and/or epicycloids.
I need to consider:
 - exploring how the relative radii of the circles relate to the path
 - develop parametric equations to describe the motion
 - Explore any other area of interest relating to cycloids

I was wondering if anyone knows of, or can explain to me, any advanced maths that can relate to these aspects or that can be used to deduce them. Any theories will smaller amounts of maths would also be of interest.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Some clocks use [gears with cycloidal shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid_gear) for accuracy.
2. The [brachistochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve) is a cycloid.

Comment: This is on the right track for what I was looking for but I was wondering if there was anything specific for cycloidal paths. Something calculus relate?